# XNA 2D TileMap seams appear between tiles

Tags: xna, 2d

I'm trying to make a 2d tile map and have run into some problems with seams appearing when layering tiles over one another. Here is a screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KFe5.png

I've tried several different ways to fix this including drawing in separate spritebatch.Begin()/End() blocks. Both layers are using the exact same code to get their position so they should be drawn directly over one another correct? Am I doing something wrong? I tried searching for an answer to this to no avail :( Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No code makes this tough to help with.

Answer (score 0):

Are you drawing on whole values? I mean Vector2(0,0) not Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f). If not you should round up.

This is better site to ask questions about game programming:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am not using whole values since the camera tracks the players position. However, I ended up setting my SamplerState paramter in the SpriteBatch.Begin() call to: SamplerState.PointWrap and this fixed the problem.

Comment: I understand, but pixels are still small, are you sure you will notice difrence when moving by whole pixels?